# Interpolation and replace existing values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, interpolation

I have a dataframe with timestamp and 32 columns. I want to interpolate some values based on the conditions in timestamp. Say my dataset looks like
[image: Sample dataset]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9QtB.png)

I want to interpolate the observations fall in t1<=timestamp<=t2 condition with new interpolated values. Interpolate function in python only replace the nan values not the existing values. How can I do that in a smart way? Could you please help me out? I am doing the programming in python. Please give suggestion based on python.

#dataset

> con = d1.loc[(d1['time']>=1582049054842.00) &(d1['time']<1582049356242.00)]

#interpolate

> con.interpolate(method='spline', order=2)

It does not interpolate any values because of there is no NaN values in the new dataset con. I want to interpolate these noise data using spline interpolation and replace the new result in the original datafile.

I also write a wavelet filtering code. This code also does not help me. Could you please suggest me a smart way to do this.

> import pywt; import numpy as np;   from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram;
> import scipy.signal as signal import
> matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
> from skimage.restoration import denoise_wavelet
> wavelet_type='db6' data = electrocardiogram()
> x_denoise = denoise_wavelet(con.iloc[:,1], method='BayesShrink',
> mode='soft', wavelet_levels=3, wavelet='sym8', rescale_sigma='True')

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how data looks like? provide some more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Desire output is just using spline interpolation replace the original values with new values.    A   B    C
               1   2     3
                4   5    6
                7    8   9
                10  11  12
I want interpolate second and third row because of they are noise. To denoise them I want to use spline interpolation filtering or wavelet filtering method for denoising and replace the new denoise data with the original data points.  I wrote this code for wavelet filtering also. But does not help.